# Get day from date in Infopath

Tags: infopath

I am using following function to get day from date. Can any body explain me how it works

```
addDays(today(), 6 - (number(substring(today(), 9, 2)) + floor(((153 * (number(substring(today(), 6, 2)) + (12 * floor((14 - number(substring(today(), 6, 2))) / 12)))) + 2) / 5) + (365 * (number(substring(today(), 1, 4)) + 4800 - floor((14 - number(substring(today(), 6, 2))) / 12))) + floor((number(substring(today(), 1, 4)) + 4800 - floor((14 - number(substring(today(), 6, 2))) / 12)) / 4) - 32083) mod 7)
```